# Unity gameobject has the wrong material

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a program which create red and yellow blocks. I want to have an array where all the blocks have to be red (userRow in the code). BTW `colors[0]` = red, `colors[1]` = yellow. The problem is when I set all the object in my array to `colors[0]` (red), there are still some blocks that are yellow.

The weird thing is that I put a debug.log and it didn't recognize that any of the blocks were yellow even though they were. I will give you a snap of the blocks that are yellow and the output.

[image: image with yellow blocks]

```
private void Generate() 
{ 
    //set the number of colored blocks numToColor = level 2 + 3; 
    // Create empty grid row = new GameObject[zNum xNum yNum]; userRow = new GameObject[zNum xNum yNum]; alltrue = new bool[yNum xNum * zNum];

     //  level
     //     numToColor
     // Create blocks
     for (int i = 0; i < yNum; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < xNum; j++)
         {
             for (int k = 0; k < zNum; k++)
             {
                 //display table
                 GameObject g = Instantiate(displayBlock, new Vector3(j * offset, i * offset, k * offset), Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, 0), displayBlockParent.transform);
                 row[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k] = g;
                 //coloring table
                 GameObject o = Instantiate(userBlock, new Vector3(j * offset, i * offset, k * offset), Quaternion.Euler(180, 0, 0), userBlockParent.transform);
                 userRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k] = o;
                 userRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[0];
             }
         }
     }
     //reverse the array because it goes from last to first
     Array.Reverse(row);
     Array.Reverse(userRow);
     //create pattern
     for (int s = 1; s < numToColor; s++)
     {
         List<GameObject> colored = new List<GameObject>();
         List<GameObject> notColored = new List<GameObject>();
         if (row.ToList<GameObject>().All(p => p.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == colors[0]))
         {
             int randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, yNum * xNum * zNum);
             row[randomIndex].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[1];
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < yNum; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < xNum; j++)
             {
                 for (int k = 0; k < zNum; k++)
                 {
                     if (row[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == colors[1])
                     {
                         colored.Add(row[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k]);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < yNum; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < xNum; j++)
             {
                 for (int k = 0; k < zNum; k++)
                 {
                     if (row[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == colors[0] && (colored.Any(p => (j != xNum - 1 && GameObject.ReferenceEquals(p, row[i * (xNum * zNum) + (j + 1) * zNum + k]))
                           || (j != 0 && GameObject.ReferenceEquals(p, row[i * (xNum * zNum) + (j - 1) * zNum + k]))
                           || (i != 0 && GameObject.ReferenceEquals(p, row[(i - 1) * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k]))
                           || (i != yNum - 1 && GameObject.ReferenceEquals(p, row[(i + 1) * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k]))
                           || (k != 0 && GameObject.ReferenceEquals(p, row[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k - 1]))
                           || (k != zNum - 1 && GameObject.ReferenceEquals(p, row[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k + 1])))))
                      {
                         notColored.Add(row[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k]);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         notColored.ToArray()[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, notColored.ToArray().Length)].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[1];
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < yNum; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < xNum; j++)
         {
             for (int k = 0; k < zNum; k++)
             {
                 if(userRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == colors[0])
                 {
                 }
                 else if(userRow[i * (xNum * zNum) + j * zNum + k].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color == colors[1])
                 {
                     Debug.Log("x: " + j + " y: " + i + " z: " + k + " || color:yellow error");
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Debug.Log("x: " + j + " y: " + i + " z: " + k + " || color: error");
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

now as you can see I have many debug.logs. It dosent log any of them. It should have logged "error yellow" but it didnt. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but I didn't see the line `Debug.Log("build: " + buildSize + " || " + GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("build").Length);` in your code .. could you maybe reduce the code example to only the minimal required code for us to reproduce the issue? Or at least add some comments to explain what exactly your code is supposed to do in general. I also don't see where you `destroy all the objects in the array`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there is another script changing the colors of those cubes. Have you checked if they are being accessed in another script?

Comment: I have seached the entire solution(I am using visuals studio) and there is no line that changes that color. also, I looked for refrences in the scene and there is only one refrence in game manager and that's normal.